# Are song leaderboards cross platform in Beat Saber?

Tags: beat-saber

If I'm playing the Steam version of *Beat Saber*, do the song leaderboards include high scores from players on the Oculus Store and Quest? Or do the [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/620980/Beat_Saber/), [Oculus](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/rift/1304877726278670/), and [Quest](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/quest/2448060205267927/) versions have separate leaderboards?

[image: Leaderboard for Immortals]

Answer (score 2):

No, the leaderboards are not cross platform on Beat Saber as looks like each console has different leaderboard. Rift/Quest/Steam/etc users will have different leaderboards.

There's [a thread about it on reddit](https://teddit.net/r/oculus/comments/8gi6ea/beat_saber_leaderboards_the_same_over_steam_and/) that tests this out and looks to be the case.